# using mysql_real_escape_string function in mysqli connection

Tags: cakephp, mysqli

I am working on Cake PHP frame work. Now I use mysqli for database connection. I would like to use mysql_real_escape_string function on code. 
What is the format for mysql_real_escape_string in mysqli connection using cakephp. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. In general: if you're using the mysqli extension, use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`.
2. In general: if you're using the mysqli extension, use *prepared statements* instead of escaping and concatenating values.
3. Specifically for Cake: [Cake already automatically escapes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html) your queries if you're using the Cake models correctly, you don't typically need to escape strings by hand. If you really do, get the datasource from the model and use its escaping function. I'm not going to detail how to do that because I'm pretty sure you don't need that.